# How do I print out a list of my facts in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

Strangely enough, the hardest part of this assignment is just printing out a list of "family members". I had no problems defining my facts and the predicates for the relationships (father, mother, aunt, uncle, ect). But for the final part I need to print out a list of the entire family.

```
male(bob).
male(jimmy).
male(richard).
female(sally).
female(sue).
female(susan).
```

These are the facts, I simply need to print them out whenever I type "showFamily". I cannot find any resource that shows how to do that. Any guidance?

The input would be "showFamily" and the desired output is

```
Family = bob, jimmy, richard, sally, sue, susan.
```

Comment: Your facts look simply like a list of genders for various names. Are you assuming all males and females are in the same family?

Comment: I have the predicates below in different code, I just honestly need to print out the names of people in the family without any relationships, just their names.

Comment: Hard to answer that without seeing your code that determines what a family member is. You said "In *the* family". What family are you referring to?

Comment: I put it in my original post. At the prompt I would type "showFamily." and the output on the screen would be "bob, jimmy, richard, sally, sue, susan". That is all I need to do.

Comment: is it possible your data represents more than one family? If so, which one do you want to show?

Comment: The actual data is moot since I just want to print these names, I am not searching through a list or anything like that, but no it is only one family. I just want to call a function called "showFamily." that will print out "bob, jimmy, richard, sally, sue, susan" on the screen.

Comment: Use `findall/3`.

Comment: Still unsure of how that is going to help me. Can you explain?

Comment: `findall(Person, (male(Person); female(Person)), Family).` but my you have a very expansive concept of family.